# Light not moving with Camera - SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit

My light doesn't follow my camera.

I've added the light as a childNode of the camera before adding the camera to the scene, and this still doesn't fix the problem.

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let scene = SCNScene()

        let shipScene = SCNScene(named: "merchant.scn")

        guard let shipNode = shipScene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "merchant", recursively: true)
        else
        {
            fatalError("ShipModel is not found!")
        }

        shipNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z:0)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(shipNode)


        let lightNode = SCNNode()
        lightNode.light = SCNLight()
        lightNode.light?.type = .omni
        lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:2, z:10)

        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:1, z:8)

        cameraNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)


        let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
        sceneView.scene = scene

        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true

    }
```

The light, regardless of the camera's position, still only illuminates the very front of the model.

Comment: Are you sure the selected answer solved this problem? I'm having the same problem, but setting `pointOfView` is not the solution, in my case. The only way I've managed to get this working is to use `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` to align the light and camera in every frame. That strategy causes light/shadow flickering, however, so it's no good. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537020/make-scenekit-light-move-with-camera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect. only missing line is as below.

```
sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode
```